# Phrases for describing earning experience points and gaining levels in gaming?

Tags: terminology

What are the common phrases/terminology for describing the act of earning experiences and building up levels during a game (probably more so in a RPG context)?

Somehow I think 'farming' is a related word, but am not sure if it is accurate. Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Why is "earning experience" and "gaining levels" not sufficient?  What are you trying to accomplish with this question?

Comment: grinding? but I'd agree with bwarner, what are you after?

Comment: Probably he's just a newcomer to the RPG genre. It can be difficult for a first-timer to understand the things that are being said in chat...

Comment: @bwarner, I'm writing an article on RPG gaming, and would like to adopt the proper wordings used by the community. thanks.

Comment: "Gaining experience" and "leveling" should be sufficient I'd think.  If you delve too far into the lingo, you can happen across strange variations that people aren't familiar with (e.g. 'exping' below) which can confuse.  Especially if writing an article, I'd prefer to err on the side of being a bit more formal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see, your options are:

<del>**Exping:** the act of gaining experience, be it through quests, missions, puzzles, treasures, or just by killing opponents.</del> **EDIT:** disregard the previous term, as it looks like it's not as widespread as I thought. Consider it just a localized version of leveling.

**Leveling:** the act of gaining levels, usually by accumulating experience points (**XP**). Generally used refering to the actual moment of going up a level ("He just leveled up"), can also be used for a continuous action ("I'm spending my time leveling")

The term "Farming" instead refers to the act of going through the same actions for long stretches of time to hoard single resources (you can farm money, minerals, items, and even XPs)

Comment: uh... exping? Never heard that.

Comment: @badp Google seems to think "exping" is synonymous with "levelling" (when searching for `exping wow` or `exping mmo`), so it can't be that rare.

Comment: Usually they're interchangeable, I've seen both terms used in the same context with no difference in the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: Never heard exping either in all my year of reading MMO boards or chat channels. Could be slang local to some community or RPG. Using it as "common phrase" would make as much sense as using "Kool" or "Rad" in article about street slang.

Comment: @Oleg I used to be a pretty hardcore MMOer (I think I literally tried over a hundred games over 6-7 years, and have clocked a thousand hours on at least a few), but I've never heard of exping. Leveling is very common though.

Comment: @Fadeway, I've only meant "exping". Fixed comment.

Comment: Modified answer. Thanks for the feedback, I really thought that "exping" was used a lot more than it really is.

Comment: grinding is another answer but has the connotation of doing nothing else during it